# Shorthand for "if typeof undefined" in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to write this in shorter and cleaner way?
I'm reading it from an XML, sometimes the URL value does not exist.

```
if (typeof(entry[i].getElementsByTagName("url")[0].childNodes[0]) !== "undefined") { 
    var foo = 'baar' 
} else { 
    var foo = entry[i].getElementsByTagName("url")[0].childNodes[0] 
}
```

Comment: As noticed by Tushar (in a deleted answer), you probably inverted both branchs, it should be "===", not "!==".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been years it doesn't make sense anymore to use this construct (unless you don't know whether the *variable*, not the *value*, is undefined). `undefined` is now read only.

Simply use

```
if (entry[i].getElementsByTagName("url")[0].childNodes[0] === undefined) {
```

In almost all cases, `typeof x === "undefined"` is a **bad practice**.

In the specific case of a DOM element, you can also simply use

```
if (!entry[i].getElementsByTagName("url")[0].childNodes[0]) {
```

because you can't have a [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) node, and of course, when the goal is to apply a default value, just use

```
var foo = entry[i].getElementsByTagName("url")[0].childNodes[0] || 'baar';
```

(be careful that this test only works when all the parts before the the last `[0]` are present, it's usually convenient to use `querySelector` or a DOM selection API like jQuery to make everything less verbose).

Answer (score 2):

```
var foo = entry[i].getElementsByTagName("url")[0].childNodes[0] || 'baar'
```

Comment: just used in console, asd= foo || "bar";, throwing error

Comment: Yes this throws error.. this is the way I tried at first

Comment: because you have not defined foo variable in console.Please declare it and then use above statement

Comment: "because you have not defined foo variable in console." Exactly and the only way to test for that is with the ugly syntax if(typeof foo === 'undefined'){...}. Is there any other way to test for undefined variables?

Comment: Good shorthand bro. Thx

Answer (score 0):

You can write in this way.

```
var ele = entry[i].getElementsByTagName("url");
if (ele && ele[0].childNodes[0]) {
    var foo = 'baar'
} else {
    //code
}
```

There is no need to check it explicitly for `undefined`.`undefined` is evaluated as `false`.